# How to match a string from the file uploaded on server

Tags: php

I have a form and the form has a text type input field where user will enter some string and they will click on search button then the form will get submitted and i have uploaded many file on my server under root directory like i have uploaded a,docs.adoc.a.txt,a.pdf like this then we need to show the files name when the user search string will be match from the  file suppose the user search string matched in a.txt and a.pdf the i wiil show the user that your search string matched in a.txt and a.pdf.

This is  my form

```
<form action="http://www.mydomainname.com/urlname.php" method="post">
<input  type="text" name="search" value=""/>
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>    
</form>
```

Comment: the files present in root folder are stored in database ? If yes, you can check using select query.

Comment: No i have just upload the file under root directory the file is not in the database

Comment: [`scandir()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) is not enough?

Comment: Use scandir() and make condition for file

Comment: I think he wants to search trough the text inside a file for a certain string?!

Comment: @TBI can you ellobarate that point that how i will make condition for matching string inside the file

Comment: scandir() function will list your files from directory then by using in_array() function of php you will check if that exists there or not

Answer (score 1):

```
$searchQuery = "abcd";
$dir = "./tests";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
        if (($file !== ".") && ($file !== "..")) {
                if (!is_file($file)) $file = $dir."/".$file;
                $s = file_get_contents($file);
                preg_match("/{$searchQuery}/",$s,$match);
                if ($match) {
                        $matchedFiles[] = $file;
                }
        }
}
if (isset($matchedFiles)) print_r($matchedFiles);
```

This should work as intended, tested it in my box. Results follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => NVS.php
    [1] => newMail.php
    [2] => post.php
    [3] => test.php
)
```

Comment: i have created two txt file a.txt and b.txt and i have written hello on booth the file then i got the tesult Array ( [0] => newsearch.txt [1] => search.txt ) but when i have changes the text written into the file to abcd and obviously i have the abcd in $searchQuery also then i got the error Notice: Undefined variable: matchedFiles

Comment: @akhilesh I edited the answer to account for the non-existence of the matchedFiles variable